# Picking a Blackberry JDE version

Tags: blackberry, jde

I am new to Blackberry programming and starting my first app soon. I believe I will be supporting OS 4.5 and higher, but now need to decide which JDE to use. I want to support the most amount of phones as possible, which is why I would guess 4.5 and higher is a good cutoff. Can anyone make suggestions of what JDE is best for features and support? I know that is very subjective. Is there a site even that lists the features of each JDE to make a good decision?

Comment: I think the other question is about IDE (development environment) whereas this question is more about the minimum JDE version (and thus minimum OS version) to support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can, I'd go down to 4.3 as the cutoff.  There are still a lot of devices out there running 4.3.  There aren't too many things that the 4.5 API can do that 4.3 can't, so you don't really gain much by setting your minimum level at 4.5.  I wouldn't go lower than 4.3, unless you want really ugly fonts!

Keep in mind that even if you pick 4.3 as your base version, you'll still need to create a separate build for touchscreen devices (Storm) using the 4.7 because that's where the touch APIs were introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I initially went with 4.2.1, but yes the initial look is a little ugly with the font. I was not sure if this was still used, but 4.3 is still doable.

Comment: The thing is, the answer changes over time.

Comment: Excellent point - devices with 5.0+ OS are now in the vast majority as of today -- so this answer is already out of date.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Below there is a list of embedded simulators for JDE versions.

JDE 4.0.2

5790
6230
6280
6710
6720
7100g
7100r
7100t
7100v
7100x
7210
7230
7250
7280
7290
7510
7520
7730
7750
7780

JDE 4.1.0

7100g
7100r
7100t
7100v
7100x
7250
7290
7520

JDE 4.2.0

8100
8100 - TMobile US

JDE 4.2.1

7130
7130e
8100
8700
8703e
8707
8800

JDE 4.3.0

8120
8130

JDE 4.5.0

8100
8110
8120
8130
8300
8310
8320
8330
8700
8703e
8800
8820
8830

JDE 4.6.0

9000

JDE 4.6.1

8900
8350i

JDE 4.7

9500
9530

JDE 5.0

8900
9000

Comment: Thanks for the information. I found a similar post on another site with this simulator breakdown.